# nested enum as dictionary key

Tags: swift, dictionary

Is there a reason why this doesn't work? Note: an enum as dictionary key works if it is not nested.

```
struct OuterStruct
{
    enum InnerEnum
    {
        case none
        case a
        case b
    }
}

var dict : [OuterStruct.InnerEnum: String] = [OuterStruct.InnerEnum: String]()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix that by using the traditional way to instantiate a dictionary:

```
var dict : [OuterStruct.InnerEnum: String] = Dictionary<OuterStruct.InnerEnum, String>()
```

Note that you can use type inference and avoid specifying the variable type:

```
var dict = Dictionary<OuterStruct.InnerEnum, String>()
```

As to why the shorthand syntax doesn't work, I don't have an answer - I think you should file a radar about that. I tried turning `InnerEnum` into a struct and a class, and the same error is reported.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Yes, I know about type inference but sometimes the compiler needs a little help. Will file a radar.

Comment: I've updated your answer with a solution for Swift 3.

Comment: @mark the original solutions I posted work in Swift 3 with no problem - just tested in a playground. What error are you having?

Comment: Hmm super weird, I'm not getting any errors anymore. Disregard my comment then. Thanks for double checking me.